# Mobile site intermittently not scrolling in Android browser

Tags: android, browser, scroll

I am new to web development for Android, and I am a bit frustrated with it at the moment. The site I'm working on (http://truthfortheworld.org) is looking and working fine on Mobile Safari, but in Android's default browser, the pages refuse to scroll down unless I refresh the page. It's quite frustrating, and I cannot figure out what's going on. Sometimes I'll load a page that looks like it's going to allow scrolling, but then it snaps to the top and won't budge.

My guess is that is has something to do with the combination of viewport settings and CSS media queries. Here's my viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

I've tried several other viewport settings, but nothing works. When I allow scaling, the page will scroll when zoomed in, but snaps to the top again once you're zoomed out.

Here's my two stylesheets:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (min-device-width:800px)' type='text/css' href='/css/main.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media="only screen and (max-device-width:1136px)" type='text/css' href='/css/handheld.css' />
```

The first is for regular screens, and the second for small devices. The worst of this problem is that sometimes it disappears for a while, everything works great, but then it starts up again. It has me baffled!

I'm using Android 2.3.4. Let me know if you have any insight for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a scrolling issue in same Android version(2.3.4). My phonegap app didn't scroll.
Because I added `overflow:hidden` in the body. When I *removed* `overflow:hidden`, it started scrolling.